# How to hide the JWPlayer 6 download button in Android Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, jwplayer, jwplayer6

How can I hide the download button that's in the right most side of the video screen in JWPlayer 6?
[image]

I am embedding it using their own 'JW Embedder' technique as below with no luck:
**mediaplayer.js**

```js
function setupPlayer(divElementId, movieFile, width, height, onReady){
    jwplayer(divElementId).setup({
        file: movieFile,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        icons: 'false',
        primary: "flash"
    });
    if (typeof onReady !== "undefined") {        
        jwplayer(divElementId).onReady(onReady);
    }
}
```